# Does the following sequence $\{g_n\}$ converge?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, limits-and-convergence

Consider a function sequence $\{f_n(t)\}$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}^+$) defined on the interval $(\frac{1}{2},1)$, where
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eqn:constraint1}
f_n(t)=\frac{\exp\left(n\left(\log R(h_t) - th_t\right)\right)}{h_t\sigma(h_t)\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(1+o\left(1\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
as $n\to \infty$ uniformly in $t$ in any closed subinterval of the interval $(\frac{1}{2},1)$,
\begin{eqnarray}
R(h)=\frac{e^h-1}{h},
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
m(h)=\frac{R'(h)}{R(h)}=\frac{e^h}{e^h-1}-\frac{1}{h},
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma(h)=m'(h),
\end{eqnarray}
and $h_t$ is the positive real root of the equation $m(h)=t$.

Then we study the following equation of $g_n$
\begin{eqnarray}
c=g_n+\frac{\int_{g_n}^1f_n(t)~dt}{f_n(g_n)},~\frac{1}{2}< g_n<1,
\end{eqnarray}
where the constant number $\frac{1}{2}< c<1$.

---

Try to prove:

1. the convergence of the sequence $\{g_n\}$ and compute $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n$;
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}n(g_n-A)=0$.

Comment: did you try to code it up? for $o(1)$ just try different things.

Comment: Can you tell where this problem comes from please. Sometimes a problem is more easily solved in its original form and then follows by applying an appropriate continuous map.